# Print when echo is read by HR-S04 sensor

Tags: serial, sensors, code-review

I'm trying to see when an echo is received by my HR-S04 sensor. I have a Serial.println within my while loop to read the signal and see once a change happens to break the loop.

The issue is my serial just prints out the pin my echo to linked to. How can I set it so that the serial output is LOW and then HIGH once an echo is received?

```
int trig1 = 3; //Trig 1
int echo1 = 4; //echo1
int ECHO1;
double pingTime1;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(trig1, OUTPUT);  //sets the digital pin 3 as output
   pinMode(echo1, INPUT);  //sets the digital pin 5 as input
}

void loop()
{
  ECHO1 = digitalRead(echo1); //assume echo1 is LOW and HIGH once echo is received

  while (ECHO1 == 0) //continuous loop until echo is HIGH
  {
    digitalWrite(trig1,LOW);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(trig1,HIGH);
    Serial.println(echo1); //Troubleshooting to see when pulse is read by sensor
   ECHO1 = digitalRead(echo1); 
  }
  pingTime1 = pulseIn(echo1, HIGH); //Measure ping travel time in microseconds
  pingTime1 = pingTime1*1000; //convert microseconds to seconds

}
```

Comment: Umm, does your code wok in the first place???

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you code isn't suppose to work. Here is a working code to start with (code below). You have a lot of mistakes so I suggest comparing your code to this one. Also, don't try to debug by adding a `Serial.print(/*something*/);` in your code.

For the time the echo is received is way too fast (under 0,001 seconds). I doupt you can use that for something useful. There is a way to calculate that using the `millis()` function, but it is quite complex for your project.

Here is a working code for the HC-SR04:

```
const int trigPin = 2;
const int echoPin = 3;

long duration, distance;

void setup() {

  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);

  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;

  if (distance < 150) {
    Serial.print(distance);
    Serial.println("  cm");
  }
  if (distance > 150) {
    Serial.println("OUT OF RANGE");
  }
  delay(20);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to record the system time when object passes by the sensor. I plan on having another sensor a little further up to record a second time. I plan on finding final time by difference then distance between sensors to compute speed.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

1) I believe your code for the trigger pin is wrong. An example I found sets it up as LOW for 2 microseconds, then HIGH for 10 microseconds, then LOW. (Note that the units are MICROseconds so you must use delayMicroseconds()

2) digitalRead(echo1) does nothing. Use the pingTime1 instead. You will always be receiving an 'echo' so it's not a HIGH or LOW but rather a changing variable stored as pingTime1.

3) echo1 is the variable for the pin. That's why Serial.println(echo1) prints the pin number. You could try Serial.println(ECHO1) but I don't think it will work because of what I said above.

4) If you want a HIGH or LOW to print to screen you must set a cutoff value for pingTime1 then use an if statement to print the appropriate value.

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but given the points above I do not believe a while loop is necessary.

Try this code. You can keep the first Serial.println() to see the duration of the pulse and/or you can keep the if statement if you want a HIGH or LOW to print to screen.

```
// Send a pulse out through trig pin
digitalWrite(trig1,LOW);
delayMicroseconds(2);
digitalWrite(trig1,HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(10);

//Receive pulse through echo pin
pingTime1=pulseIn(echo1, HIGH);
pingTime1=pingTime1*1000;

// Serial print
Serial.println(pingTime1);

//Serial print (for HIGH or LOW)
if (pingTime1 > cutoff) {
    Serial.println('HIGH');
}
else {
    Serial.println('LOW');
```

Comment: I'm trying to record the system time when object passes by the sensor. I plan on having another sensor a little further up to record a second time. I plan on finding final time by difference then distance between sensors to compute speed.

Comment: Okay, you might want to clarify the question in your post. Just use an if statement to 'trigger' the sensors. (if within certain distance, record time)